# Swift Error while trying to print variable from alert-view textfield

Tags: variables, swift, alertview

I have this code here that runs an alertview and shows a textfield asking for the subject name

```
 alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default, handler:{ (alertAction:UIAlertAction!) in
            var textf= alertController.textFields[0] as UITextField
            self.items += [self.textf]
            println(self.items)
            println(textf)
            self.view .setNeedsDisplay()

        }))
```

And then Im declaring the variables items and textf out of that function at the top of the code using this code

```
var items = ["English"]
let textf = ""
```

but the problem is that when I run my app and click on my button that shows the alertview and i type in my subject and click ok I get this error when it tries to print out string. It just prints out this error and it does not close my app

```
<_UIAlertControllerTextField: 0x7f9d22d1c430; frame = (4 4; 229 16); text = 'irish'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7f9d22cc55f0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7f9d22d1c6e0>>
```

It says in the error the text I typed in but It is not adding it to the variable because when i print out the array `items` it prints out

```
[English, ]
```

and not

```
[English, irish]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is weird...

```
var textf= alertController.textFields[0] as UITextField
self.items += [self.textf]
```

`var textf` and `self.textf` are *two different variables.* It looks like `self.textf` is the empty string you set outside your function. So an empty string is what's getting added to the `items` array.

You also have another problem. You seem to want a string, but your `var textf` value is a `UITextField`. You need to snag the `text` property if you wan the string.

This confusion is why I like explicit typing. If you are expecting a `String` and have a `UITextField` the compiler will catch that if you explicitly type your variables.

Which means you need something more like this:

```
var items: [String] = ["English"]
var textf: UITextField? = nil // this variable optionally holds a text field

// later, inside some function...
func somefunc() {
    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default, handler:{ (alertAction:UIAlertAction!) in
        self.textf = alertController.textFields[0] as UITextField
        // append() is preferable to += [], no need for a temporary array
        self.items.append(self.textf!.text)
        println(self.items)
        println(textf)
        self.view.setNeedsDisplay()
    }))
}
```

Comment: Thanks it is adding text f to the items array, but the only thing is that I am still getting that error when I print out textf which I think is strange as the items array gets the text would you know why this would be happening

Comment: That's not an error. That's a `UITextField` being converted to a string, which is exactly what you would expect when printing a `UITextField`. If you wan the string, then: `println(textf!.text)`